Angular Material 2: Floating Outline Label cut due to missing space
I am using a mat-dialog and inside a title, content and action buttons. Inside the content i have put two mat-form-fields with appearance="outline".
When nothing is added between <mat-dialog-content> and the <mat-form-field appearance="outline"> the outlined label gets cut due to added zero top padding on the mat-dialog-content container.
.mat-mdc-dialog-container .mat-mdc-dialog-title+.mat-mdc-dialog-content {
    padding-top: 0;
}

When inserting something between the <mat-dialog-content> and the <mat-form-field> the oulined label no longer gets cut as on the top of the <mat-dialog-content> there is added space- which is required to display the floating label properly.
ps: a simple string, a html element, an empty img tag... all works.

Fix: Adding padding-top to the dialog-content fixes it.
Is there any wrong import i have done- so may the dialog of the FormField is not working correctly?
Component ts
Angular 17 Standalone
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialogContent, MatDialogActions, MatDialogTitle } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatFormField } from '@angular/material/form-field';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-user',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatDialogContent,
    MatDialogActions,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDialogTitle,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatFormField
  ],
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html',
  styleUrl: './add-user.component.scss'
})
export class AddUserComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddUserComponent>
  ) { }

  closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}

